# RedirectPermanent is not working in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

What I am missing here?? It is not working. Thanks

```
public ActionResult GotoFacebook()
    {
        return RedirectPermanent("www.facebook.com");
    }
```

I have tried it also

```
public ActionResult GotoFacebook()
        {
            return Redirect("www.facebook.com");
        }
```

Comment: What does it do when you call that action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing **http://**

```
return RedirectPermanent("http://www.facebook.com");
```